# E-mail on registration showing very strange characters!!! я│п╟п╧я┌п╣

Tags: emails

I developed the website in English, then enabled the locale module ,i added Russian language..i also set it as a default language to my website.
But when user register they got strange characters in their emails!!!!!! is there any settings do adjust to fix this?

//below is my user settings.
Who can register account=Visitors
E-mails(Welcome no approval required!)==i change the Text to russian

[user:name],

Вы успешно зарегистрированы на сайте Бесплатных купонов http://www.example.ru!
Теперь вы можете получить скидки Бесплатно!

Логин: [user:mail]
Пароль: Ваш пароль

Просим вас не отвечать на это сообщение автоматичеческое рассылки.
--  [site:name] Команда

//and here the example of the email sent to user
п▓я▀ я┐я│п©п╣я┬п╫п╬ п╥п╟я─п╣пЁп╦я│я┌я─п╦я─п╬п╡п╟п╫я▀ п╫п╟ я│п╟п╧я┌п╣
п▒п╣я│п©п╩п╟я┌п╫я▀я┘ п╨я┐п©п╬п╫п╬п╡ http://www.example.ru!
п╒п╣п©п╣я─я▄ п╡я▀ п╪п╬п╤п╣я┌п╣ п©п╬п╩я┐я┤п╦я┌я▄ я│п╨п╦п╢п╨п╦
п▒п╣я│п©п╩п╟я┌п╫п╬!

п⌡п╬пЁп╦п╫: someone@mail.ru
п÷п╟я─п╬п╩я▄: п▓п╟я┬ п©п╟я─п╬п╩я▄

п÷я─п╬я│п╦п╪ п╡п╟я│ п╫п╣ п╬я┌п╡п╣я┤п╟я┌я▄ п╫п╟ я█я┌п╬ я│п╬п╬п╠я┴п╣п╫п╦п╣
п╟п╡я┌п╬п╪п╟я┌п╦я┤п╣я┤п╣я│п╨п╬п╣ я─п╟я│я│я▀п╩п╨п╦.
-- Example.ru п п╬п╪п╟п╫п╢п╟

Your help to resolving this will be appreciated.

Comment: what email client is the end-user using to receive these emails? have you tried registering on your own and seeing what results you get back? drupal sends these emails out utf-8 encoded, the end-users client may not be handling these correctly (quick check through google translate and it shows the garbled characters are assumed russian at least)

Comment: The web is free registration, everyone can register.. i try to register am also getting this.